# Pandas specify datatypes

Tags: python, pandas

```
pandasframe_datatypes= ['A':int64, 'B':object, 'C':object, 'D':object, 'E':float64]
```

It is used like so:

```
test = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep=";", names=pandasframe_names, dtype=pandasframe_datatypes)
```

But it gives a syntax error, what is wrong?

A is an integer, B and C and D is a string, E is a float.

What would the correct answer look like?

Also my csv has a header column and if I specify the names, the first column is doubled. Is there a solution for this as well?

Comment: `pandasframe_datatypes` is not valid python syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change not valid dictionary:

```
import numpy as np

pandasframe_datatypes= ['A':int64, 'B':object, 'C':object, 'D':object, 'E':float64]
```

to valid dict and also use valid `dtype`s for numeric columns:

```
pandasframe_datatypes= {'A':np.int64, 'B': object, 'C': object, 'D':object, 'E': np.float64}
```

Or:

```
pandasframe_datatypes= {'A':'int64', 'B': object, 'C': object, 'D':object, 'E': 'float64'}
```

Comment: NameError: name 'np' is not defined. What can I do?

Comment: @Smiley - add `import numpy as np` only. Or `pandasframe_datatypes= {'A':pd.np.int64, 'B': object, 'C': object, 'D':object, 'E': pd.np.float64}`

Comment: This doesnt work. I get ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A' Could it be that my first column is double?  how can I remove header (which contains some names) when I read the csv otherwise I get a datatype error and cannot cast to this datatype.

Comment: @Smiley - It is expected, because bad data, cannot convert `A` to numeric, need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas)

Comment: thanks a lot, I added skiprows=1 as a parameter and if I get something like ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 6, what can I add? Could I insert null in this case? If so, how would I do that

Comment: @Smiley  possilble solution is use [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html)

Comment: using: pd.array(['NA', np.nan, None, pd.NA], dtype="Int64")
TypeError: object cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype - how could I change the value on import instead to NULL ? It it would make sense if it first tries to convert to the correct type and only if it fails to replace by NULL. How could I do that? thanks so much.

Comment: @Smiley - I think in `read_csv` really complicated, maybe some converter is necessary, dtype cannot be used here if bad date types